# In Java, how can I pass an array directly as a parameter to a function?

Tags: java, arrays, function, parameter-passing

I am working on a Java project and have a number of arrays generated by a different script (e.g. {1, 2, 3, 5}).

I have these arrays in a notepad and would like to pass them directly to a function which would put them in a hasmap of the form HashMap<String, Int[]>. These Hashmaps will subsequently be placed in another hashmap.

Now I wrote a function that took in the parameters necessary to create the larger hash (thus Hashmap<Int, Hashmap<String, Int[]>>) which takes Int, String, and Int[] as function parameters.

My problem is that Java wants me to first make up a Int[] (e.g. array_of_numbers1 = {1, 2, 3}) before allowing me to pass that Int[] as a parameter in the function that creates the HashMap.

Is there any way for me to do this directly, wihtout the need to pass to first create a Int[] variable before passing that into the function? So directly pass an array into a function call?

I would love for my function call to look like (where my function is: Public Void AddElement(Int, String, Int[]))

AddElement(1, "Numbers1", {1,2,3}) etc.
Is this way of passing parameters even possible? Could it be done in a different way so that I could still use a list, or a sequence of numbers which would together be placed in an array (in the function) so that I could would not have to initialize a Int[] array first (such as AddElement(1, "Numbers1", 1, 2, 3,....possibly more numbers or not))?

The error I get is "Array initializer not allowed here". What could be done to work around this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want varargs. `int... ex` is syntactic sugar for `int[] ex`, but lets you use the end of the parameter list as your array input, e.g. `callMethod(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is:

```
AddElement(1, "Numbers1", new int[]{1,2,3})
```

——

Only when declaring a variable/field can you use the shorthand version, eg

```
int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks a bunch! I was already kind of desperate since I realised that without declaring the type of the array it would never be accepted, but this is exactly what I needed to do! Thanks again, I'm guessing this question can be closed. What a great site with quick help!

Answer (score 1):

The standard form of making an array, initialized with numbers of your choosing, is:

`new int[] {1,2,3}`, e.g:

`addElement(5, "Hello", new int[] {1, 2, 3});`

You can omit the `new int[]` part of that, but only if you use this expression as the initial value of a new field or variable declaration, and not when passing to a method call:

`int[] example = {1, 2, 3};`.

If you make your method argument 'varargs', you can just pass an infinite amount of int parameters, though. You are probably looking for this:

```
public void addElement(int rowKey, String columnKey, int... values) {
    map
        .computeIfAbsent(rowKey, r -> new HashMap<>())
        .computeIfAbsent(columnKey, c -> new HashMap<>())
        .put(values);
}

addElement(5, "Hello", 1, 2, 3);
```

You may get a warning here in some IDEs, which is trying to say that if someone creates an array, and uses that to call a varargs method, they can then later change the array and this changes the array in your map store:

```
int[] example = {1, 2, 3};
addElement(5, "Hello", example);
example[0] = 6;
System.out.println(getElement(5, "Hello")[0]);
// prints 6 - that may not be what you want
```

If you dislike this; make a copy of the array in your `addElement` method: `.put(Arrays.copyOf(values));`

Note that this problem applies if you use `int[]` too; it's just assumed that you know about it if you write `int[]`, so most IDEs don't generate the warning then.

Answer (score 1):

> I would love for my function call to look like (where my function is: `Public Void AddElement(Int, String, Int[]))`

> `AddElement(1, "Numbers1", {1,2,3})` etc.

Use varargs.

```java
public void addElement(int i, String s, int... values)
```

```java
addElement(1, "Numbers1", 1, 2, 3);
```

There can only be one varargs parameter, and it must be the last parameter.

Also, notice how almost all the words in the code starts with lowercase letter. The code in the question is not Java.